# how to make Transformable image in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to make Transformable image in swift with core data. 
I create imageA that is Transformable.
when I try to see is there image in database it tells that there is nothing there.
how to add image to database ? what is wrong with my code?
here is my code

I use methods setImage
and getImage in place where saving and getting works for @NSManaged var isSet: NSNumber?

```
extension AppSettings {

    @NSManaged var isSet: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var imageA: UIImage?

}

func setImage(inputAppSettings : AppSettings)
{
    let theImage = UIImage(named: "image.png")
    inputAppSettings.imageA = theImage
}



func getImage(inputAppSettings : AppSettings)
{
    if let theImage = inputAppSettings.imageA
    {
        print("theImage: \(theImage)")
    }
}
```

class MyTransformer:NSValueTransformer{

```
override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool
{
    return true
}


class func transformedValue(value:AnyObject) -> AnyObject
{
    var returnData:AnyObject = NSData()
    let theImage = value as! UIImage
    if let theData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(theImage)
        {returnData = theData}

    return returnData
}

class func reverseTransformedValue(value:AnyObject) -> AnyObject
{
    var returnImage:AnyObject = UIImage()
    let theData = value as! NSData
    if let theImage = UIImage(data: theData)
        {returnImage = theImage}

    return returnImage
}

override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass
{
    return UIImage.self
}
```

}

```
func set()
{
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
    let theAppSettingsAnyObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("AppSettings", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
        if let theAppSettings = theAppSettingsAnyObject as? AppSettings
        {
            theAppSettings.isSet = true
            self.setImage(theAppSettings)
        }
        var savingError: NSError?
        do {
            try moc.save()
         } catch let error1 as NSError {
            savingError = error1
        if let error = savingError{
            print("Failed to save . Error = \(error)")
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `UIImage`, which conforms to `NSCoding`. As a result, **you do not need a custom value transformer**, because `UIImage` already has that covered. All you need to do is:

1. Declare the attribute to have type `Transformable` in the Core Data model editor
2. Read and write `UIImage` to that attribute. Transformation to/from a binary form will be handled by `UIImage`.

Comment: I do not need all code related to subclass of NSValueTransformer
and I do not need to change @NSManaged var imageA: NSObject?

Comment: to @NSManaged var imageA: UIImage?
Is it so?
In this case image do not save to core data.

Comment: Yes it's so. You don't need a custom transformer for a class that adopts NSCoding. If it's not working, make sure you changed the attribute type to "transformable".

Comment: I set attribute type for imageA  to transformable in .xcdatamodeld file

Comment: is there any sample code with transformable image for swift?

Answer (score 0):

To Store image in Database is heavy operation, it will take more time to encode and decode or in transformation.

Instead of transformation, **try to save image in Document directory, and store its url in database.**

Comment: thanks for answer . but in case of small image and only 1 image to store it i think will be less code if I will use transformation so I still need this way.

Comment: Core Data will take care of that. If the data blob is to big it will be stored in an external file.